# Detect if a file is being changed

Tags: php, ftp

I am frequenty getting "unexpected end of file" errors, I think they only happen on included files and not the base files themselves. But anyway they happen whenever I upload a file at the same time a user happens to load a page that uses the file that's being uploaded.

How would I go about detecting whether a file is being uploaded? Or is there some way to configure my FTP client (I use FileZilla) to read-lock files while uploading?

Comment: what's in the files? once you have finished developing them *not on the live site* you should only have to upload once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should upload to an temporary directory, and switch the completely-uploaded file with the old file.

Comment: Thing is, iterations go by so fast - we sometimes go through a hundred iterations in a day. Having to move files from a temporary directory to their actual place would seriously slow things down...